# Is there a utility which do retrieve file format information?

Tags: windows, file-format

There is a *file* utility in linux.
The users can get file format information by *file*.

I'd like to use this program in my application.
Is there a Windows utility? Open source is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File has been ported to Windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Answer (score 2):

**[trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)** might be a possibility - its used in computer forensics to identify files. Unlike file, it uses a database, rather than magic numbers

Answer (score -1):

Check [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545046), it is bound to have one that suits your needs. It's not open source, though.

Comment: I don't recall any file identification tools in the sysinternals family